# running rsync command through cygwin from a python script

Tags: python, cygwin, rsync

I’m trying to get this working, but I keep getting

```
subprocess.call(['c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe', '--login', '-i', 'rsync', '-zrgo', '--omit-dir-times', '--verbose', '--delete', '.', 'usertwo@192.168.1.1:/var/www/project/'])
```

--

```
bash: /usr/bin/rsync: cannot execute binary file
126
```

Comment: Does the same command work if you manually enter it in a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the '-c' (command) option to bash. Also you should provide the rsync command as a single string:

```
subprocess.call(['c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe', '--login', '-i', '-c', 'rsync -zrgo --omit-dir-times --verbose --delete . usertwo@192.168.1.1:/var/www/project/'])
```

From the man page:

```
-c string If the -c option is present,  then  commands  are  read  from
          string.   If  there  are arguments after the string, they are
          assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
```

For example:

```
# bash /bin/ls
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
# bash -c "/bin/ls -l"
<ls output>
```

Comment: AMAZING! THANK YOU! There is one small problem though, if I put . it tries to use the current cygwin directory but then if I put the full path to the directory it tells me `The source and destination cannot both be remote.`

Comment: what is the full path you use? does it have a colon (:)?

Comment: the full path is S:/myproject/root/ so i want  S:/myproject/root usertwo@192.168.1.1:/var/www/project/

Comment: yeah, rsync will interpret the ':' as a remote path (it is originally a Unix tool and Unix paths don't have ':' in them). Try: `cd S:/myproject/root/; c:/cygwin/bin/rsync ...` as the command string, leaving '.' as the source directory.

Comment: It works! This is incredible thank you so much isedev. I'm using /cygdrive/s/myrpoject/root